# Detect Locked object on the oracle package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

There is a package which used to trigger every 10 minutes as a batch process and it would take 3-5 minutes to complete. Jobs are often getting failed with the error message -

> ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource.

Need your help to find out the exact object which is being locked by some other process on the environment and caused the job failure.

I have referred many blogs/forums and didn't found any solution. Please note as this is the production - there might be many objects on locked status. Any help would be appreciated to narrow down the issue?

Comment: A deadlock causes details to be written to the alert log. Check that.

Comment: the deadlock details are in the corresponding trace file, not in the alert.log file. It tells you which two sessions are blocked and what object they were trying to access. This is always an application error as the application tries to lock objects in a different order.